# Ruby: nested array structures (many levels) transformed into one array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array structure:

```
[[a], [b, c, [d, e]]]
```

That could have many levels of nesting (defined in execution time)

I would like to transform it in:

```
[a], [b,c], [d, e], ...
```

I have not found a way that works for 100% of the cases.

Any suggestion?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean by `[a], [b,c], [d, e]` - do you mean `[ [a], [b,c], [d, e] ]`

Comment: Array#flatten doesn't solve this problem as stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000280) should do the trick?

Comment: flatten will return `[a,b,c,d,e]` for the example input.

Comment: Thank you. Ir worked. Also tried:
a * ","
Where "a" is the nested structure.
But your solutions is more elegant

Comment: @Gregor: Don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem.

Comment: @sepp2k: You can pass a number to flatten, such as `flatten(1)`.

Comment: @Andrew: Sure, but that wouldn't give you the sample output either. `[[a], [b, c, [d, e]]].flaten(1)` is `[ a, b, c, [d, e] ]`, not `[ [a], [b,c], [d, e] ]`.

Comment: @Andrew: well, you could change the level of recursion on the flatten function

Comment: @sepp2k is right..how did you get the output using Array#flatten? or is ur output different from that is stated in the question..your expected output in the question doesnt make much sense..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the output using flatten is

```
 [a, c, d, e] (depending of the level of recursion you use in flatten)
```

In fact, that output worked for me, I was over complicating desiring the 
    [ [a], [b,c], [d, e] ]

Never the less, could be interesting to know the process for that particular output.

Comment: gosh, this was supposed to be a comment for the answer! Sorry!